# C# powershell ErrorDetail usage

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a custom powershell command derived from `PSCmdlet` and on error I want to provide my own error message. As per MSDN `ErrorDetails` propery on `ErrorRecord` does that :

> Provides additional error information for an error record, such as a
>   more detailed replacement error message.

How ever I am not able to get it working, I have `DisplayStrings.resx`, in this I have stored my custom error message with the ID `InvalidOrNoSite`, but when I execute the following code, it shows the same old style error and not my custom error.

```
ErrorRecord err = new ErrorRecord(new ArgumentException(), "", ErrorCategory.InvalidArgument, this);
err.ErrorDetails = new ErrorDetails(this, "Resources.DisplayStrings.ResourceManager", "InvalidOrNoSite", null);
ThrowTerminatingError(err);
```

Any examples on how to use ErrorDetails?

Answer (score 0):

The *customisation* of `ErrorDetail` works if you change your error in a `non-terminating error`.

This behaviour is not explained in microsoft documentation *[ or at least I have not found it :) ]* but in a book I've buy some year ago ( Wrox - Professional Windows PowerShell Programming - February 2008 ) at page 97 is reported that in `terminating error` doesn't work.

My workaround is to set a *'flag'* variable to `true` in the `catch` and after test this variable and do or not do some or all following code.